# Fixed position images scrolling issues

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, wordpress

I have a site that uses fixed position, rotating and scaling images as a header that link through to external sites. The images are wider then the container div. Everything works pretty well except that when you scroll the page the navigation goes over the top of the images in the header due to the fixed position. I was wondering if there was a was to clear the fixed elements or prevent the navigation from scrolling over the slideshow? Here is a link to the site: http://www.ginkandgasoline.net/

Answer (score 0):

the slideshow images have a "position:fixed"... therefore everything is working like it should. to solve your scrolling-problem, just remove this...

Comment: when i do this they images are no longer scalable.

Comment: ..but the images will NEVER scroll with the page, as long as they are fixed positioned. also, when i'm deactivating this line, the images still remain "fullscreen"